# Splitting a column horizontally into multiple columns based on a common value in other column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table A as my input in Oracle SQL. 
Table A:

```
+-----------+---------+------+-----+
|    Col1   |  Col2   | Col3 | Col4|  
+-----------+---------+------+-----+
|      a    |    g    |   1  | ABC |   
|      b    |    h    |   2  | ABC |
|      c    |    i    |   1  | DEF |
|      d    |    j    |   2  | DEF |
|      e    |    k    |   1  | GHI |
|      f    |    l    |   2  | GHI |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+
```

I want to split each of column 1 and column 2 horizontally based on the value of col4. Col3 is either 1 or 2 as shown. 
Output table:

```
+-----------+---------+------+-----+----+
|    Col5   |  Col6   | Col7 | Col8|Col9|
+-----------+---------+------+-----+----+
|      a    |    g    |   b  |  h  | ABC|   
|      c    |    i    |   d  |  j  | DEF|
|      e    |    k    |   f  |  l  | GHI|
+-----------+---------+------+-----+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 ) 
  SELECT 'a', 'g', 1, 'ABC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', 'h', 2, 'ABC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c', 'i', 1, 'DEF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'd', 'j', 2, 'DEF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'e', 'k', 1, 'GHI' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'f', 'l', 2, 'GHI' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT N1_C1 AS Col5,
       N1_C2 AS Col6,
       N2_C1 AS Col7,
       N2_C2 AS Col8,
       Col4 AS Col9
FROM   table_name
PIVOT ( MAX( Col1 ) AS C1, MAX( Col2 ) AS C2
        FOR Col3 IN ( 1 AS N1, 2 AS N2 ) );
```

**Output**:

```
COL5 COL6 COL7 COL8 COL9
---- ---- ---- ---- ----
a    g    b    h    ABC  
c    i    d    j    DEF  
e    k    f    l    GHI
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a straight application of a self-join:

```
with 
     test_data (col1, col2, col3, col4) as (  
       select 'a', 'g', 1, 'ABC' from dual union all
       select 'b', 'h', 2, 'ABC' from dual union all
       select 'c', 'i', 1, 'DEF' from dual union all
       select 'd', 'j', 2, 'DEF' from dual union all
       select 'e', 'k', 1, 'GHI' from dual union all
       select 'f', 'l', 2, 'GHI' from dual
     )
select td1.col1 as col5, td1.col2 as col6, td2.col1 as col7,
       td2.col2 as col8, td1.col4 as col9
from   test_data td1 inner join test_data td2 on td1.col4 = td2.col4
where  td1.col3 = 1 and td2.col3 = 2
;

COL5 COL6 COL7 COL8 COL9
---- ---- ---- ---- ----
a    g    b    h    ABC
c    i    d    j    DEF
e    k    f    l    GHI
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when col3 = 1 then col1 end) as col5,
       max(case when col3 = 1 then col2 end) as col6,
       max(case when col3 = 2 then col1 end) as col7,
       max(case when col3 = 2 then col2 end) as col8,
       col4 as col9
from tablea a
group by col4;
```